# GET запрос c токеном

Tags: java, android, post, get, token

Осваиваю android. Мне нужно сделать GET запрос с токеном, который у меня в формате JSON/String

```
{"token"="21848274897189"}
```

Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Смотря как принимает контроллер. Наверное в хидеры запроса. Все гуглится, только захотеть осталось.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем json объекте есть ошибка, правильно будет не равно, а через двоеточие:

```
{"token":"21848274897189"}
```

1. По существу вопроса - вы можете записать любые параметры в URL в виде:

```
https://host/service?token=21848274897189
```

в java в методе контроллера такой параметр сопровождается аннотацией `@RequestParam`

2. Или второй вариант, когда мы не именуем параметры:

```
https://host/service/21848274897189
```

в java в методе контроллера такой параметр сопровождается аннотацией `@PathVariable`

3. Альтернативное решение - вы можете указывать кастомные заголовки к вашему HTTP-запросу и записывать туда произвольные данные.

в java в методе контроллера такой параметр сопровождается аннотацией `@RequestHeader`

4. Так же, технически возможно передать параметры в теле GET-запроса, но это не рекомендуется. Посмотрите ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/3744622

в java в методе контроллера такой параметр сопровождается аннотацией `@RequestBody`